# How to LineWrap a text in JTextPane that is layouted with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, gridbaglayout, word-wrap

I use a Jpane with a GridBagLayout. In the GridBags I put a JTextPane component.
But I can't linewrap my text in the JTextPane when I resize the JFrame.
Here is my code...

```
package problems;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrollbarTest {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JScrollPane [] scrollpane = new JScrollPane[4];
private JTextPane [] textPane = new JTextPane[4];
private JScrollPane scrollbar;


ScrollbarTest() {
    //initialize jtextarea
    for(int i=0;i<textPane.length;i++) {

        textPane[i]=new JTextPane();            
        textPane[i].setText("xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx | ");
        scrollpane[i] = new JScrollPane(textPane[i]); 
    }

    panel     = new JPanel();
    frame     = new JFrame();

    createList(panel);
    scrollbar = new JScrollPane(panel);

    frame.add(scrollbar);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));          
} //constructor

//method to easily add components to GridBags
static void addComponent(JPanel panel, 
                         GridBagLayout gbl, 
                         Component c,
                         int x, int y,
                         int width, int height,
                         double weightx, double weighty) {

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = x; gbc.gridy = y;
    gbc.gridwidth = width; gbc.gridheight = height;
    gbc.weightx = weightx; gbc.weighty = weighty;
    gbl.setConstraints( c, gbc );
    panel.add( c ); 
}//addComponent

public void createList(JPanel panel) {
    //setting layout: "GridBagLayout"
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();        
    panel.setLayout(gbl);                        

    //put created components to the gridbags of gridbaglayout
    //                                            x  y  w  h  wx wy
    addComponent( panel, gbl, scrollpane[0]     , 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,0  );
    addComponent( panel, gbl, scrollpane[1]     , 0, 2, 1, 1, 1 ,0  );
    addComponent( panel, gbl, scrollpane[2]     , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,0  );
    addComponent( panel, gbl, scrollpane[3]     , 1, 2, 1, 1, 1 ,0  );
} //createList

public static void main (String[] args) {
    new ScrollbarTest();        
} //main

} //end of class
```

Where is the problem?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You are using JTextPane or JTextArea?

Comment: There is no JTextPane in above code .. am I missing something?

Comment: actually the same code as above, but JTextPane instead of JTextArea

Comment: ok, i've changed the code. Now it is written with JTextPane components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing [setLineWrap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29) on your JTextArea.

```
for(int i=0;i<textArea.length;i++) {
        textArea[i]=new JTextArea();
        textArea[i].setLineWrap(true);
        textArea[i].setText("xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx | ");
    }
```

**EDIT**

> in the case of JTextPane you shall create a scrollpane with no
>   horizontal scroll policy and set your JtextPane as its viewPort

Comment: thank you! And how do I have to handle the lineWrapping with JTextPanes?

Comment: Thank you. Now I've put each JTextPane into a scrollpane. How can I set the viewPort? sorry, I'm little bit confused..

Comment: Glad it helped you. . Please upvote/accept answer .. hv fun coding :)

Comment: another question: my components have always a fixed size. Can I manually resize the JScrollPane or JTextPane component??